# Questions which solicit opinion

Tags: discussion

According to https://magento.stackexchange.com/faq#link-dontask  we should refrain from unanswerable questions.

Can you please describe to me the major differences between this question which solicits opinion:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/585/top-reasons-to-switch-to-enterprise-edition

And this one:

[What is the Best Magento Server Setup?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/460/what-is-the-best-magento-server-setup/466)

If this is not the forum for this discussion, fine. Understood. However - is it possible that I asked it wrong? Is it possible to frame such questions in an acceptable way to get the input of the most prominent developers in the Magento community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have said its in the phrasing. You are asking a broad question with no specific answer.

In the comparative question, there were specific points that could be answered.

> - must come in under 200ms in the UK
> - 2 dedicated web servers, load balancer, 1 db server
> - coming in at 800ms.
> - 5 customers, 2 products, 4 categories,
> - EngineX with Varnish.
> - Need to get 400% quicker!

Given the information he provided, I was in a good position to give him some relevant and direct advice. What software to use, how to best utilise his existing equipment, what targets were realistic etc.

---

For example, *if* the [What is the Best Magento Server Setup?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/460/what-is-the-best-magento-server-setup/466) question merely said:

> If you could say the 3 things that sped up your Magento store the most, what would they be

You'd get answers of varying levels of accuracy and relevance; all of which are valid to the person writing the answer; but not necessarily someone else. The individual answers might each be of benefit to the community at large - but would there be one overwhelming/clear answer?

I've always been of the opinion that for the coding-type SE sites; there is (and should be) 1 best answer.

---

Your question comes across more as a seeding type question than whether you were actually considering buying EE. Did ***you*** actually want or need the answer?

Perhaps if your question was more along the lines of

> - 5,000 products, 50,000 page views
> - Not performing as well as we hoped
> - Sometimes find ourselves fixing core bugs
> - When is the tipping point to upgrade, do you think we'd benefit

Then again, I'd be able to tap into my experience of the stores we manage and give you an educated answer.

But as your question currently stands, I don't think I could provide a meaningful or valuable response?

My goal on SE is to help others, I enjoy it. But I can't help you with your question because there is not enough information or direction on how to answer it.

Comment: I will admit that I personally do not need the input - but I feel it is helpful for others to hear the experiences of those on EE. I have worked with EE for 3 years exclusively. The spur for the question is based on Magento's own push for CE to EE upgrades - found here:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/community-to-enterprise  - their **3 bullets** approach is FPC, Abandon Cart and Tech Support. Personally I think the community could come up with 3 better reasons to switch. That's the purpose of the solicitation. I'm not offended - merely trying to find my place in this community.

Comment: As an example. You could imagine a response to someone's answer of `FPC, Abandon Cart and Tech Support` being --- **FPC** - can be provided via many different 3rd party extensions. **Abandon Cart** can be provided via many different 3rd party extensions. **Tech Support** - expect to wait weeks to a response; that will be vauge, unhelpful and accusatory. --- I don't know, I just figure it starts a debate as no-one's one answer is going to be the same as another answer, or even *the* answer.